# How to show scroll bar always in alertdialog in android?

Tags: android

I have alertdialog builder which shows multiChoiceItems, there are many items so all options are not visible and scrollable list is created but scroll bar hides after some seconds. How can I make it visible all the time?

I'm not using custom builder. I know this method but how can I use it setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false)?

Comment: As I said i'm not using custom alertdialog so there is no layout.xml
I created alertdialog builder and populated it from java code.

Comment: you can use Dialog instead of AlertDialog and add a scrollview to the layout.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this to a AlertDialog builder. However it is possible to do it to AlertDialog.

Get the AlertDialog from your builder.

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Then you have to show your dialog before you manipulate it.

```
dialog.show();
```

Now the methods are available and won't throw errors. Note: You can style your positive and negative buttons here too.

```
dialog.getListView().setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```